# Facebook DeviceLoginButton and LoginButton Difference for Android

Tags: android, facebook-login

Refactoring my code I found this option to use com.facebook.login.widget.DeviceLoginButton`or`com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` and the look pretty much the same.

The DeviceLoginButton extends the LoginButton, but when I should use one or other? what's is the difference?

Even look the [Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices) from Facebook they don't talk anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DeviceLoginButton**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/DeviceLoginButton/)

> DeviceLoginButton(Context, AttributeSet, int)

This control requires the **`app ID and client token`** to be specified in the AndroidManifest.xml.

[**LoginButton**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/)

> LoginButton(Context)

This control requires the **`app ID`** to be specified in the AndroidManifest.xml.

**FYI**

The client token is an identifier that you can embed into native mobile binaries or desktop apps to identify your app.

Read [**`Access Token`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Comment: If I cannot specify the Client Token, why would be better to do? So I can user the DevideLoginButton?

Comment: @Canato `If I cannot specify the Client Token` Then you should use `LoginButton`

Comment: sorry, I was not clear. Since I can use facebook login specifying the client token and without specify, why I would specify?
Why specify is better?